# Orientation specific failure in ListView.layoutChildren -- exception ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException

Tags: android, exception, listview

I am a very green android developer and need some help with a strange program crash. Often the program will run just fine.  There is an equal chance it will fail (see stack at the end).  I can watch the program run through the getView function and everything seems in order (i.e. all the information is there as expected and passes through convertView seemingly fine).  Either it will go through a few times and then program will be A-OK or it will fail as seen below and I have not been able to pick out what causes the crash.  Even stranger is that if I hold the phone in landscape mode, it will never fail!!  It only fails about 50% of the time in portrait orientation.  Can someone please help me?

```
        @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        }
        ADDPResults addpres = items.get(position);
        if (addpres != null) {
                //initialize display variables from inflated row.xml variables
                TextView iptext = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.IPtext);
                TextView mactext = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.MACtext);
                TextView nametext = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.Nametext);
                TextView devicetext = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.Devicetext);
                //TextView firmwaretext = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.Firmwaretext);
                //write the real data to the display
                iptext.setText("IP Address:     "+addpres.addp_deviceIP.toDecString()); 
                mactext.setText("MAC Address: "+addpres.addp_deviceMAC.toHexString() );
                nametext.setText("Name:             "+addpres.addp_devName);
                devicetext.setText("Device:           "+addpres.addp_devType);       
                //firmwaretext.setText("Firmware:       "+addpres.addp_FWVersion);
        }
        return v;
    }
}
```

-----------------------Failure----------------------------------------------
Thread [<3> main] (Suspended (exception ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException)) 
 ListView.layoutChildren() line: 1686 
 ListView(AbsListView).onLayout(boolean, int, int, int, int) line: 1224 
 ListView(View).layout(int, int, int, int) line: 6886 
 LinearLayout.setChildFrame(View, int, int, int, int) line: 1119 
 LinearLayout.layoutVertical() line: 998 
 LinearLayout.onLayout(boolean, int, int, int, int) line: 918 
 LinearLayout(View).layout(int, int, int, int) line: 6886 
 FrameLayout.onLayout(boolean, int, int, int, int) line: 333 
 FrameLayout(View).layout(int, int, int, int) line: 6886 
 LinearLayout.setChildFrame(View, int, int, int, int) line: 1119 
 LinearLayout.layoutVertical() line: 998 
 LinearLayout.onLayout(boolean, int, int, int, int) line: 918 
 LinearLayout(View).layout(int, int, int, int) line: 6886 
 PhoneWindow$DecorView(FrameLayout).onLayout(boolean, int, int, int, int) line: 333 
 PhoneWindow$DecorView(View).layout(int, int, int, int) line: 6886 
 ViewRoot.performTraversals() line: 996 
 ViewRoot.handleMessage(Message) line: 1633 
 ViewRoot(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
 Looper.loop() line: 123 
 ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 4363 
 Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method] 
 Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 521 
 ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 862 
 ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 620 
 NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check what you get as 'position' and compare that to the size of your items array... since the exception says : ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: I checked that.  Typically there are 5 items in the array and 'position' never goes above 4 as expected.  Usually the crash will happen on the 'Position=4' iteration but not always.